# Removing ASCII Characters In A String

Tags: java, ascii

I am trying to remove the ASCII char(11) from the String. I can see the char(11) represents ' '. However, when adding this as a String "' '" it turns out to be "''".

How can I check that the actual is a ASCII character ' '?

The code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("' 'The name is stack");
    int value = 11;
    char data = (char) value; // in debug mode this is ' '
}
```

I want to delete this ASCII char if if exists at index 0. The problem is that the string is "''" instead of "' '". How can this be achived?

I want the output to be The name is stack.

Comment: It is according to http://ascii.cl/. Can char(11) in ASCII be removed from a String? If yes, how?

Comment: ASCII char 11 is a VT (vertical Tab) if I am not mistaken

Comment: That's right. You are right.

Comment: what do you want to remove?. whitespace?

Comment: I mean a string of characters and char(11) to be removed from the String at index 0 if char(11) exists.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
if (stringBuilder.charAt(0) == data) {
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Do the 2 characters actually match? Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/homZnD) showing the character being removed

Comment: The characters don't match. The stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0) is never executed.

Comment: @user3189663 You could build a new `StringBuilder` by trimming the content of the original builder. Note this will remove all characters less than '\u0020' as well as leading & trailing spaces

Comment: `StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder(stringBuilder.toString().trim());`

Answer (score 0):

I think the first "printable" character is the space symbol, at index 32. So drop anything below 32 and you should be fine. Should be trivial to extend to cover the whole string.

You can assign characters as int values, and they correspond like shown [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
        char[] chars = new char[4];
        chars[0] = 31; // character for unit separator
        chars[1] = 65; // A
        chars[2] = 66; // B
        chars[3] = 67; // C

        // build a string from the printable and unprintable chars
        String s = new String(chars);

        // check length and how it prints out
        System.out.println("[" + s +"]");
        System.out.println(s.length());

        // if char at index 0 < 32, drop it
        if(s.charAt(0) < 32)
          s = s.substring(1, s.length());

        // prints like previously, but length is now smaller
        System.out.println("[" + s +"]");
        System.out.println(s.length());
```

Comment: what does 32 represent?

Comment: 32 is just space, so " ". if the char value there is below it, it isn't usually "printable" i think. Refer to the link in my answer for a table of ascii characters

Comment: char(11) is a vertical tab accoriding to the link that you have attached. How can a vertical tab be removed from a String?

Comment: @user3189663 it is a character just like any other, how it is shown is somewhat different though :)

Comment: How can a vertical tab be seen in Java. There are many for example '\r', '\n' is a vertical tab. How can I identify which one is a vertical tab?

Comment: \n is newline, \r is carriage return, they both have their own ascii codes as well. Java does not have such representation for vertical tab.

Comment: See java languange specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html, section 3.10.6 for what is allowed